Scalafx: UnsupportedClassVersionError
I'm trying to use Scalafx in project.
Dependencies are:
   ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.1"

   libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "3.0.2"
   libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" %% "scalafx" % "22.0.0-R33"

And I got the the following exception:

java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: javafx/application/ColorScheme has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

I use Java 8 for this project. It corresponds to the 52.0 major version
I set jdks\corretto-1.8.0_412 in IntelliJ IDEA Project Structure. And set this value for JAVA_HOME
What did I miss?
This answer jdk version doesn't help me.

First update your Scala version to the latest 2.12 patch, that will help prevent some errors in the future. Second, it seems that version of Scalafx does not support Java 8, either look their docs for a version that still supports Java 8 or update your Java to a newer version.

The release notes are very clear about only supporting Java 17: https://github.com/scalafx/scalafx/releases/tag/v.22.0.0-R33 - I would advice using that JDK version and also using Scala 3 or 2.13 rather than keep using old technologies.

The error means that the javafx.application.ColorScheme class was compiled targetting Java 17 (class version 61), it cannot run on Java 8. You need to use Java 17 or higher, or use an older version of the libraries that are still compatible with Java 8.
